# Launching GCE VM instances with software already on it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to launch a VM instance with a .zip file already installed in the vm or install it as soon as the VM launches, i will be working with node js and the gcs api or if not it it possible with any

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Can you please show us what you have tried so far and exactly what it is that does not work ans intended?

Comment: Please be more specific. There is a difference between installing a 100 KB script and configuring an enterprise application. What is your goal, what you have tried, what documentation have you read, and after that research and preparation, what software development problem do you need help with?

Comment: it will be ~10 ~250mb desktop apps made in electron or other desktop app building software. I just want them installed or have the server install them for me as soon as i launch the vm. all the apps can be downloaded over the web.

Answer (score 2):

For that you can consider 2 options :

**Option 1 (recommended)**

You can add a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) on your Compute Engine VM, which will download your zip file from Google Cloud Storage, and then do some custom stuff for example.

Let say we have an application file called `app.gz`, and consider the `bash` startup script example below:

```
#! /bin/bash

/usr/bin/gsutil cp gs://my-startup-bucket/app.gz /tmp/.
/bin/gzip -d /tmp/app.gz

# some custom stuff to setup app
# ...
```

Copy application file and startup script to the GCS bucket :

```
gsutil cp app.gz gs://my-startup-bucket
gsutil cp startup-script.sh gs://my-startup-bucket
```

During creation process of new VM, set `startup-script-url` as metadata :

[image: Set startup script url]

You can check that script was correcly executed, inside `syslog` log :

```
tail /var/log/syslog -n 100
...
vm-setup startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: Copying gs://my-startup-bucket/app.gz...
vm-setup startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: / [0 files][    0.0 B/   38.0 B]                                                #015/ [1 files][   38.0 B/   38.0 B]
vm-setup startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: Operation completed over 1 objects/38.0 B.
vm-setup startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: Return code 0.
vm-setup startup-script: INFO Finished running startup scripts.
...
```

Note that, Compute Engine default service account must have permission to access to the GCS bucket.

**Option 2**

Create a new instance based on a [custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images) with your files preinstalled.

To do that, steps are :

- create a vm
- customize the vm with application setup, or just files...
- create a snapshot
- create an image from this snapshot
- create each new vm with this image